# Office documents NOT opening from Sharepoint 2013 Document Library

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-addin, office-web-apps

I have a document library with the name field being the link to the document.

If I try to open MS word documents I receive a warning and then and the an authorisation of credentials. I ok the warning and cancel the authorisation (I am already logged in with full permissions). At this stage word opens but no document loads.

I am able to right click on the link and the document will open in word but not from the sharepoint link - any clues out there or is someone experiencing the same problem?

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: variety - server 2008r2, windows 7, windows 8

Comment: browsers IE9, IE 10, Safari, Opera, Firefox, chrome (also mobile browsers)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is WebClient.
Try to enable or install it, here is the steps:

Windows 2008 Server: http://windowsadminblog.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-to-enable-webclient-service-on.html

Windows for desktop: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnguin/archive/2012/06/24/enabling-the-webclient-service-in-windows.aspx

Comment: Thanks AmitKB. I have ensured the webClient is available. I am still experienceing the same issue. Our old intranet contains the same office documents with html links. When the document is requested the authentication is prompted here also. Once the request is cancelled the document opens in the client application. It is a similar problem but it still works in a difficult way. Sharepoint will open the client application but not load the document

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if users tick the "sign me in automatically" check box the user credentials are passed to the office client.